# Kafka Best Practices + how to set recommended setting for JVM

Tags: java, jvm, apache-kafka

A recommended setting for JVM looks like following

```
-Xmx8g -Xms8g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80
```

my question is - How do I set the above Java options for Kafka?

I know for sure that we can set

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8G -Xms8G"
```

but not sure if we can append the whole line

```
"-Xmx8g -Xms8g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"
```

to **KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS** variable

reference - https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/80813/kafka-best-practices-1.html

Comment: yes you can, have a look on how it is done in `/bin/kafka-server-start.sh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check `kafka-run-class.sh`, here you can see what env variables kafka uses to start the java process:

- `$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`
- `$KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS`
- `$KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS`
- `$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS`
- `$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS`

and then it run the java application passing them:

`nohup $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS....`

basically the content of the env variables are just appended as is to the command, it does not really matter where you put the settings as soon as the jvm parameters are in the correct order.

So, you can simply change `$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` however to keep the variable names consistent with their content I would put `-Xmx8g -Xms8g` in `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` and the remaining optimization to `KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS`.

Comment: what you think about to set that ( in kafka-env template  ) , export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"   , is it also right syntax instead to separate the values in two variables

Comment: not really because if empty default will apply, see `if [ -z "$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" ]; then
  KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M"
fi
`

Comment: in that case I will prefer to do the following -  export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"   and export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=" -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 - XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 - XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"

Comment: do you except this above ? ( since I use ambari I will set both variable in kafka-env template )

Comment: should be ok, you can then verify the actual invocation with `ps -aux | grep java`

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, `-Xmx8G -Xms8G` should be set using `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`.

For the other configurations you listed, you should probably use `KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS`.

I'm not aware of a place where all the supported environment variables are clearly described. The best is to check the [`kafka-run-class.sh`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/a63f464f5ec28cc4891b1b356355f4a0f08bb991/bin/kafka-run-class.sh) tool, as it is called by all the tools, including `kafka-server-start.sh`.

For example:

- `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` is used here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/a63f464f5ec28cc4891b1b356355f4a0f08bb991/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L273-L276
- `KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS` is used here https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/a63f464f5ec28cc4891b1b356355f4a0f08bb991/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L278-L282

Comment: @Michael , can you answer please to Paizo , seems he not agree with you